# bootstrap navbar doesnt align as expected when toggled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why is the `<ul>` elements does not align properly(the home active link should and the rest of the toggled link should be under brand) as seen on the image.

[image]

**The Code:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Sample Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean they 'don't align properly'. Could you elaborate and tell us what you want it to do and show us your CSS code?

Comment: the active home link should be under the brand as i see on the tutorial i watched

Comment: i dont have any pure css code just bootstrap framework.

Comment: I believe the Bootstrap Nav is usually aligned horizontal to other elements. If you want to change it, use CSS.

Comment: yes it should. but i dont know why its not horizontally aligned. XD cant figure it out.

Comment: Can you give us some information and you should try to use CSS. With CSS you can do vertical-align: left I believe

Comment: honestly i hate front end development but i realized to study it so i can make my own design and i cant cope witth css. thanks sir

Comment: I mean, the tutorial is fine, but it's old and bootstrap updated.

Comment: i cant find a good bootstrap tutorial until i found that youtube channel and his tutorial

Answer (score -1):

after i show the tuturial there is problem with bootsrap css .
the button has float:right element and we need to clear it.

please add class to your css file

```
.clear{
clear:both;
}
```

then use your code with this class

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Sample Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse clear">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddle here -

https://jsfiddle.net/05aah0tb/

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer, but a comment. If you only have >50 reputation, consider not using answer to communicate, but wait until you can comment everywhere

Comment: here is the tutorial i watched earlier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpWlaOeGZ_4 his navbar perfectly worked may be i messed up my code